# Facing Invalid Package Information Error while upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.2

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my PC, and I'm encountering an error "Invalid Package Information" while trying to upgrade it to 22.04.2. During the upgrade, a message appears stating: "After updating your package information, the essential package 'ubuntu-minimal' could not be found." As a result, the upgrade process terminates. Please guide me how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.